# Create a GeoServer feature using a SQL Server 2008 View

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, geoserver

We are trying to create a feature (layer) in GeoServer on top of a view in SQL Server 2008, rather than a table. We are able to create the feature, but it won't display any data because GeoServer (JDBC) can't detect a primary key to use as the FID. To the best of my knowledge, it is not possible to make a view column appear to be a primary key, and we can't figure out how to force GeoServer to recognize a specific column as the FID.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After many hours of digging, poking and prodding, I am inclined to believe this is not currently possible. I'd love to be proven wrong, but in the mean time we'll be migrating our app to PosgreGIS, which hopefully will be a matter of changing the dialects in the NHibernate config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was apparently a known bug in the SQL 08 GeoServer driver. They have since fixed the problem, and the fixed version can be obtained by downloading one of their nightly builds. You'll need to get the latest copy of both GeoServer and the SQL Server driver.